# Blender numpy.float32

Tags: python, numpy, blender

I've only a short question.
Currently I'm writing an addon for Blender. Everything works fine, but when I want to add the vertices and faces to the current Blender-Scene, I got the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/blender/scripts/modules/bpy_types.py", line 378, in <listcomp>
vertices_flat = [f for v in vertices for f in v]
TypeError: 'numpy.float32' object is not iterable
```

EDIT:
Here ist the code:

```
def add2Scene(self,verts):
    print("Adding object to current scene")
    triMesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("MCIsosurface") 
    triMesh.from_pydata(verts , [], self.faces)
    triObj = bpy.data.objects.new("MCIsosurface", triMesh)
    #triObj.setLocation(0,0,0)
    bpy.context.scene.objects.link(triObj)
    print("done")
```

Comment: Can you paste more of the trace, so we can see the point in your code when it fails?

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the Problem

I stored the position like this: 
 X Y Z X Y Z

Blender need the data like this

((XYZ),(XYZ))

so a simple reshape solved it:

```
verts = self.vertices.reshape(len(self.vertices)/3,3)
```